# Fast hostname/IP check in Python?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I have a list of hostnames and I want to check if these machines are running or not in an interval of about one second.

What I have until now is this, but the timeout on the machines which are offline take some seconds:

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(0)
def resolve_hostname(hostname):
    try:
        return socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    except socket.error:
        return False
```

Not good as the list has about 30 machines.

Any ideas how to speed things up a bit?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a classic use case for multithreading. Launch each request in a new thread. You can't get the timeouts to occur any quicker though.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `gethostbyname` just looks up `hostname`, and does not connect to the host. It might not be affected by the timeout. Is it possible that name resolution is taking some seconds?

Comment: @101 thanks, I will look into that.

Comment: @kai the timeout does change. In default it takes about 5-6 seconds and with no timeout it takes 2-3 seconds. The machines wich are on are beeing found in miliseconds.

Comment: This code does not check whether the machine is running, only whether it's name can be resolved. It is possible (for example if the name is set in `/etc/hosts`) that this will return a hostname even if the machine is not running. (edit: this was before I saw your reply)

Comment: @kai Yes, I know it's not ideal, but I should work for me since I'm only looking up local machines. I anyway need to get the ip-adresses via the hostname. I see that this isn't clear in my question-post, sorry.

Comment: @Till the timeout seems to work using `socket().connect()` here, though I'm not sure what would happen if the hostname lookup was slow. I'll post my code and you can try it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of coding this up yourself, I would look into using a third-party mass DNS resolver. Here is one that looks promising:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/berserker_resolver/1.0.3

To install:

```
pip install berserker_resolver
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> import berserker_resolver
>>> resolver = berserker_resolver.Resolver()
>>> to_resolve = ['www.google.com', 'www.microsoft.com', 'www.facebook.com', 'invalid.invalid']
>>> resolver.resolve(to_resolve).keys()
['www.microsoft.com', 'www.facebook.com', 'www.google.com']
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get the code to resolve local hostnames. Any idea on how to achives this? Tried a couple of things, but the entry is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a connection with a slow name lookup to try, but the timeout seems to be respected exactly for `socket.socket.connect()`

```
import socket

def test_hostname(hostname, port, timeout=1.0):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(timeout)
    try:
        s.connect((hostname, port))
    except (socket.timeout, socket.gaierror):
        return False
    else:
        return True
    finally:
        s.close()
```